# How do you improve performance of a view without any joins or where conditions?

Tags: oracle, performance, view

I have a simple view which takes columns from table based on pipeline characters (as varchar2 data type) and convert some columns into numbers. I'm having a very difficult time in loading full records from the source table to target table through the view. Is it possible to improve it's performance?

The view looks like the below with 150 column splits and 35 conversions

```
CREATE OR FORCE MYVIEW as
WITH CommonTableExpression
AS 
(SELECT   
a.* 
,CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.Line, '([^|]*)(\||$)',1,1,NULL, 1) AS VARCHAR2(1)) Column1
FROM  MYTABLE a)
SELECT 
LINE
,CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR (Line || '|', '([^|]*)(\||$)',1,1, NULL, 1 ) AS NUMBER(1,0)) Column1_NBR
FROM CommonTableExpression;
```

I was never able to load the full 16,00,000 records and it takes 15 hours to load one third of the table.

Comment: So... you just have 2 output columns, and the second one is just extracting a 1-digit number from the front of the string, right? Could you show example data and expected output? I feel like I'm missing something, this seems overly complicated.

Comment: The code represents only the basic structure of the view. Like Column1, there are up to Column 150 and like Column1_NBR, there are up to 35 columns.

Comment: Ah, ok, and at some point you're actually selecting the values from `Column1`, right? Because here it's never used.

Comment: You should post a sample of the data (not all 150 columns) and some expected output derived from that sample. You don't have to, it will just massively increase your chances of getting a timely and helpful response.

Comment: Anyway, the basic problem is that regexp functions are very expensive to execute. You're chewing through 16 million instances of a very large string. So, basically you're paying the tax for not storing your data in First Normal Form. (I'm aware this was probably not your decision, you've just been lumbered.) Given that you can't change the scope (that is, you're stuck with the data in MYTABLE as it is) all you can do is reduce the amount of work you do with regex. Maybe, try using INSTR() or SUBSTR() instead, because they are more efficient.

Comment: Thank you @APC. As you said regexp was too taxing. I was able to use instr() and substr() as you said. What took 3 hours now takes 4 mins.

Comment: Glad to be of service